# Python and Pandas: How do I shorten string values from an individual column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner to Python and Pandas, both, but I'm having a little trouble in something that I feel could be done pretty simply. I'm trying to shorten the string values of an individual column to just the abbreviations you see at the end. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

This is my current code below, just showing the list of drivers from the column    `Driver`.

```
In[1]: drivers=df_results[0].loc[0:, 'Driver']

Out[1]:0      Sebastian  Vettel  VET
       1      Lewis  Hamilton  HAM
       2      Kimi  Räikkönen  RAI
       3      Daniel  Ricciardo  RIC
```

As you can see, there are the names followed by the abbreviations, but I only want the abbreviations (`VET`, `HAM`, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the last three characters like this:

```
drivers.str[-3:]
```

You could also use [`drivers.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then take the last part.

Comment: Beautiful, John, thank you very much. When I do that, how can I make it so my dataframe 'df_results' , remembers, in a sense, the abbreviation and stores it in my dataframe. For example, when I print(df_results) it still shows the full length of the names. I don't know if you need visualization, but hopefully that explains it.

Comment: @metincs: You can overwrite the old values by `drivers[:] = drivers.str[-3:]`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick help, John. This worked perfectly and definitely helped me learn some new tricks!

Answer (score 1):

To add to John Zwinck answer, simply assign drivers.str[-3:] to a new column.

```
df_results['new_column'] = drivers.str[-3:]
```

Comment: Thank you, Ajay. I'm just starting to work with dataframes and this is some advice I will definitely implement in the future, maybe even later in this project!